# Laravel Join with 2 GroupBy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, group-by, php-7

can you help me solve this problem?

I want to combine the two tables

transaction_ppob
transaction_sosmed

In the table there is a column containing the status, I want to count the amount
success, wait, and error in table 1 and table 2

Here is the code

```
$status = DB::table('transaction_ppob as ppob')
    ->join('transaction_sosmed as sosmed','ppob.user_id', '=', 'sosmed.user_id')
    ->select('sosmed.status', 'ppob.status', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupByRaw('sosmed.status, ppob.status')
    ->get();
```

How do you calculate the second column?

transaction_ppob

- success
- success
- pending

transaction_sosmed

- pending
- error

Comment: (1) Why are there 2 success messages in `transaction_ppob` and none in `transaction_sosmed` (2) What happens if `transaction_ppob.status='Success'` and `transaction_sosmed.status='error'`?